# How to parse the jason data using a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

So the HTML is

```
<select name="city">
  <option value="Mysuru">Mysuru</option>
  <option value="Bagalkote">BagalkoteBagalkote</option>
</select>
```

in java script I have to parse a JSON file using the above drop-down value.

the js code is:

```
app.post("/", function(req, res) {
var city= req.body.city;
```

So in the above code I took the data from html post

now I have a json data which is parsed:

```
var jdata=JSON.parse(body);
```

So now I need the particular data from the jdata

```
var activecases=jdata.Karnataka.districtData.city.active;
```

here city is a variable which contains the cityname but now doesn't work it shows error that city is not defined....
but if i put Mysuru instead of city it works... but I need to put city there because it will be varying every time as the person chooses different city in HTML...

Pls someone help me out..

the json file is https://api.covid19india.org/state_district_wise.json

Comment: Can you post your json data as well?

Comment: https://api.covid19india.org/state_district_wise.json

Comment: this is the Json file

Comment: You need to do this. `var activecases=jdata.Karnataka.districtData[city].active;`

Comment: why dont you post this in answer.. i will upvote it..if you dont mind @Yadab

Comment: You are welcome. Glad that I am able help. You have marked your question as duplicate hence no one can add answer. If you remove the duplicate I can post an answer for it.

Comment: @yadab i cannot remove the duplicate since they have marked my question as inappropriate...chuck....anyway this was my first question in stackoverflow and i never taught someone will answer my question.....thank you soo much sir (#ExpectTheUnexpected)

Comment: Well, the point here is to help people and fix the problem. So I am happy for that.

Comment: @Yadab can you help me out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67363931/cannot-read-property-username-of-undefined-something-to-do-with-body-parser

Answer (score -1):

Try select tag with name attribute:

```html
<select name="Karnataka[districtData][city][active]">
</select>
```