# Cannot read property 'username' of undefined...something to do with body-parser

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

I need to log the username from the file register.ejs to my console

i have checked the code soo many times and i couldn't get the solution the is error.. plz help me out
this is my /register file:

```
          <!-- Makes POST request to /register route -->
          <form action="/register" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email">Email</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" name="username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="password">Password</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Register</button>
          </form>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This is my app.js file:

```
const express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();

var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true });
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(express.static("publica"));

const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/userDB", {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: String,
  password: String,
});

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("home");
});

app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
  res.render("login");
});

app.get("/register", (req, res) => {
  res.render("register");
});

app.post("/register", function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body.username);
});
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("All Good Bruh!!!");
});
```

im trying to log the username from /register page but im getting this error:

```
Cannot read property 'username' of undefined
```

Please help me out

Comment: Setting up the body parser is not enough, you need to tell express to actually use it. `app.use(urlencodedParser);` should do it.

Comment: no bro thats not working too :((( same error

Comment: and also in the above code i have used

`var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true });`

Comment: No you haven't. All you have is `var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true });` which by itself does absolutely nothing. You need to add the line from my comment below, or simply do `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));`

Comment: wowww i got it broo!!! Thank you soo much broo!!! Means a lot...

Comment: @ChrisG Answer for the Question bro,,,i will give upvote :))))

Comment: The answer is basically this: http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html#examples so I'm not going to post one.  Glad it's working now though :)

Comment: Yeah thanks broo!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));`

some where up